# Can generics be used to collapse these methods?

Tags: c#, generics

I have two methods that do very similar things but with a different return type (string vs int)

Here they are:

```
private static string LoadAttributeString(this XElement xmlElement, 
                                          string attributeName, string defaultValue)
{
    try
        {return xmlElement.Attribute(attributeName).Value;}
    catch (Exception)
        {return defaultValue;}
}

private static int LoadAttributeInt(this XElement xmlElement, 
                                    string attributeName, int defaultValue)
{
    try
        {return int.Parse(xmlElement.Attribute(attributeName).Value);}
    catch (Exception)
        {return defaultValue;}
}
```

Is it possible to use generics to combine these into one method?  (I tried and failed.)

NOTE: I am fine having two different methods.  I would just like to expand my knowledge of generics.  So I thought I would ask if it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) instead of a specific parsing function.

```
private static T LoadAttribute<T>(this XElement xmlElement, 
                                  string attributeName, 
                                  T defaultValue)
                                  where T : IConvertible
{
    try
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(
            xmlElement.Attribute(attributeName).Value, 
            typeof(T));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

By the way, catching `Exception` is generally a bad idea. Do you definitely want to hide null reference bugs?

As I like the generality of Jared's answer, I can't resist rewriting mine as a mere overload to his:

```
private static T LoadAttribute<T>(this XElement xmlElement, 
                                  string attributeName,
                                  T defaultValue) 
                                  where T : IConvertible
{
    return LoadAttribute(
        xmlElement, 
        attributeName, 
        x => (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T)), 
        defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: virtual -1. This only works for types that implement `IConvertible`.

Comment: I'm glad it's a virtual -1, as the question asks about int and string, which are supported by `Convert.ChangeType`.

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker - I agree that usually it is a bad idea to catch `Exception`.  But in this case I really just want to either load the value, or a default.  I don't care what goes wrong, if ANYTHING goes wrong at this point I want a default value.

Comment: @Vaccano - I hear ya... I just wonder if in a few months time you'll wish you had a stack trace, not just a default value. :)

Comment: Is there a way to limit the types that can be used with this method to those that implement `IConvertible`?

Comment: @Vaccano - yes. But that includes all the built-in numeric types, bool, string, DateTime... in other words, most things you'd store in an XML attribute.

Comment: @Vaccano - I've added the necessary `where` modifier to restrict `T` to types that implement `IConvertible`.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following

```
private static T LoadAttribute<T>(
  this XElement xmlElement, 
  string attributeName,
  Func<string, T> convertFunc,
  T defaultValue) {

  try {
    return convertFunc(xmlElement.Attribute(attributeName).Value); 
  } catch (Exception) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
}
```

Here are some example use cases for `string` and `int`

```
LoadAttribute(xmlElement, someName, x => x, defaultValue);  // string
LoadAttribute(xmlElement, someName, Int32.Parse, defaultValue);  // int
```

Comment: Minor gripe, but wouldn't Converter<string, T> be more appropriate? ;)

Comment: @x0n, i prefer to use the `Func<...>` and `Action<...>` versions over their named counter parts. I don't know of any guidelines in this area but my experiences in other languages (F# in particular) shaped my preference of this pattern.

Comment: the `Converter<in TIn, out TOut>` is contra-/covariant in .NET 4 though, whereas the `Func<T1, TResult>` is not.